# Spring Boot & JPA - aggregate results from a flat table

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

It will sound like a very trivial (and I hope it really is) thing, but I don't know how to do that purely using JPA, neither if it worth doing.

Is it possible to aggregate values in a JPA fashion fetching data from just one flat table?

Example:

Table

| company_id | company_name | employee_id | employee_name | employee_role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Google | 100 | Fred M. | Admin |
| 1 | Google | 101 | Axel R. | Auditor |
| 1 | Google | 101 | Joanne W. | Manager |
| 2 | Amazon | 200 | Rick M. | Admin |
| 2 | Amazon | 201 | Matt H. | Auditor |
| 2 | Amazon | 201 | Jack N. | Manager |

Projection / Entity

```
interface Summary {
   Long getCompanyId();
   String getCompanyName();
   List<Employee> getEmployees();    
}

interface Employee {    
   Long getId();
   String getName();
   String getRole();
}
```

Repository return:

```
List<Summary> findAllSumaries();
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  I misread the question. If you do a minor edit I can cancel my downvote (it doesn't let me otherwise)

Comment: Ok @DavideD'Alto, np